# How to fetch QueryString values without using GET?

Tags: php, ajax

My AJAX code is passing QueryString to a PHP file. The QueryString looks like this:

```
var strUrl = "./lib/filldropdown.php?DivName = " + DivName + "&DropDownControlName = " + DropDownName + "&SqlQuery = " + SqlQuery;
```

In the file "filldropdown.php", I want to fetch the values from the query string. How to do this without using GET? And also, please let me know whether the query string is written correctly or not.

Comment: Perhaps you could also explain why you don't want to use GET in the first place?

Comment: Because GET is not working. I tried it, but it is not picking values.

Comment: In that case, the thing to do is figure out what's going wrong. Paul's answer holds the key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to use $_REQUEST['...'], which will both respond to params sent via POST|GET.

Comment: you may also want to remove those spaces between the =
ex: ?DivName = " + DivName + "
try ?DivName=" + DivName + "

Answer (score 2):

Ummm. `$_GET['DivName']` should be one piece of your data. Just to note

- Don't build the query string yourself. Build a JS array and use a javascript library (I recommend JQuery) to do the QS creation
- The `=` shouldn't have spaces
- Passing an SQLQuery in your params is *A BAD IDEA*. I will quickly hack your app, the second I see that. Look up little bobby tables.

Comment: -1 If he's not already using it, bringing in jQuery just to make a query string is a horrible idea and outright overkill. +1 for pointing out the security flaw with the sql parameter.

Comment: +1 for spaces, which is why the OP thinks PHP isn't picking up the input. An underscore will take the place of spaces in key names.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're using `$_GET` and not `$GET` or something else.  If it's really broken (which might be due to some sort of config issue, but I haven't heard of this happening before).  `$_REQUEST` might work for you, or you can try to get the query string from `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`, but you'll have to parse it yourself.

As [Paul Tarjan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1774940/how-to-fetch-querystring-values-without-using-get/1774951#1774951) pointed out in his question, the query string is not correct nor is safe to pass SQL queries to a PHP script.  They should always be generated server side with strict sanitation on any user provided data.

Comment: @Justin: I am using $_GET and not $GET.